# Change android theme dynamicaly

Tags: android

I'am developping app where user can change THEME (dark&white). I have created two themes. But I do not know how let user to change it any time in app.
I want ot implement it using switch.
As I understood I should change dinamically Style file, probably this line

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Can someone help me? because I can not find propper tutorial

Comment: You want to entire app theme to change?

Comment: yes...you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two themes that define different background colors and text colors:

```
<resources>
<style name="BlackTheme" >

<item name="android:background">#000000</item>

<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>



<style name="BlueTheme" >

<item name="android:background">#B0E0E6</item>

<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

</style>



</resources>
```

Open your layout file and enter the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView

android:id="@+id/textView1"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

android:layout_marginTop="14dp"

android:text="@string/pick"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



<Button

android:id="@+id/blackbutton"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"

android:text="@string/black" />



<Button

android:id="@+id/bluebutton"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignRight="@+id/blackbutton"

android:layout_below="@+id/blackbutton"

android:text="@string/blue" />



<EditText

android:id="@+id/editText1"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"

android:layout_below="@+id/bluebutton"

android:ems="10"

android:hint="Name"

android:inputType="textPersonName" >



</EditText>



<TextView

android:id="@+id/textView2"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"

android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"

android:text="@string/agree" />



<EditText

android:id="@+id/editText3"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"

android:ems="10"

android:hint="Password"

android:inputType="numberPassword" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="black">Black</string>

<string name="blue">Blue</string>

<string name="pick">Pick Your Colour</string>

<string name="agree">I agree to the terms and conditions</string>
```

Open the new file and enter the following:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;


 public class themeUtils

{

private static int cTheme;



public final static int BLACK = 0;

public final static int BLUE = 1;

public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)

{

cTheme = theme;

activity.finish();



activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));


 }

public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)

{

switch (cTheme)

{

default:

case BLACK:

activity.setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);

break;

case BLUE:

activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);

break;

}

}

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

themeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

findViewById(R.id.blackbutton).setOnClickListener(this);

findViewById(R.id.bluebutton).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override

public void onClick(View v) 

{

switch (v.getId())

{
case R.id.blackbutton:

themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeUtils.BLACK);

break;

case R.id.bluebutton:

themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeUtils.BLUE);

break;

}

}

}
```

Take a look at your work.

[image] [image]